Importing xlsx data from Pandas to SQL Server, receiving string data, right truncation and text column data incomplete
I have an xlsx file that I'm trying to run through Python to edit and then upload to our database.
For vendor A, their data comes in through a CSV and I've been able to edit and upload that no issue.
Vendor B has their data come in through an xlsx file, and when I get to the import stage I'm getting this error:
Starting Copy:
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation

Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Text column data incomplete
SQLState = 23000, NativeError = 515
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'My_database.dbo.My_Table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
SQLState = 01000, NativeError = 3621
Warning = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.

BCP copy in failed

Here is the table in the databse:
ID int Primary Key,
WritingAgentName varchar(max),
WritingAgentNumber varchar(max),
PolicyNumber varchar(max),
CommissionPct decimal(4,2),
EffectiveDate datetime,
CommissionAmt decimal(6,2),
TransactionDate datetime,
StatementDate datetime,
ProductName varchar(max),
BillingDueDate datetime,
Role varchar(max),
SplitWith varchar(255),
FirstYearOrRenewal varchar(max),
CommissionType varchar(max),
InsuredName varchar(max),
ModalPremium decimal(6,2),
CarrierID int

The other issue is the "cannot insert value NULL into column 'ID'". This sounds like I need to manually input the values for the ID column, but the csv import didn't need that. Is there something different with using xlsx?
I initially had varchar(255) for those columns, but when researching this I found that the right truncation error means the column can't hold the data and to make it max size. That still hasn't worked unless I did something wrong.
I've also tried limiting the number of rows to find the error, but on .head(1) I still get the truncation and 'text column data incomplete' error.
Not sure what part of the code to share but if you let me know what more info is needed I can share. I'm confused because the same import statement for Vendor A works but not for B and I'm assuming it's something with the data itself that I need to fix, just lost on what specifically.

It's suspicious that you'd need varchar(max) (2GB capacity) on most of your columns, but you do still have a shorter one, SplitWith varchar(255).

Did the .csv files supply values for the ID column? Or was your previous code generating them? Also be aware that Excel likes to keep empty rows around when deleting cell contents (as opposed to selecting entire rows and right-click-deleting them from the gutter). You could try exporting the problem .xlsx file to a .csv and opening it in Notepad, etc. (not Excel) to see if there are blank lines at the end.

Considering this looks like Insurance data, I would say that if you are working with an Insurer that requires Policy Numbers that are longer than 8,000 characters, that you have a very frank conversation with said Insurer. At the office the longest policy number we have is 18 digits (and that's with 100+ insurers).

The problem is likely in the file data itself. You can always convert the "good" file to excel and see if anything goes wrong and vice versa.

@AlwaysLearning The .csv did not have an ID column, and I didn't add one in python either. On the import it worked just fine and assigned an unique ID to each entry.
I copied it to a notebook and I'm not seeing any blank lines at the end.
The Split With varchar (255) was an oversight on my end lol, I missed updating that one I guess.

@ThomA The policy numbers are around 12 digits long.

So why is it defined as likely to be more than >8000 characters, @JacobLindsey ? Why are any of those columns defined like that.

Like I said in my post, I saw that the right truncate error meant the data was larger than the columns, and the first fix was to increase the varchar column sizes. Clearly that hasn't worked so I'm here for help find the issue.

Debug it the way everyone else does, start with a single, simple, column test, and then work up adding more columns until it fails, fix whatever fails and keep building up - thats assuming there is no way to get more details about which columns are failing.

@DaleK how do I go about testing certain columns? I can test rows with df.head but I'm struggling to get specific columns. Do I need to create multiple test tables with certain columns missing?

Create a test spreadsheet with 1 column and a test table with 1 column..
